# How do I configure an additional context path for tomcat-maven-plugin?

Tags: tomcat, maven-2, maven, maven-tomcat-plugin

I'm using Maven 3.0.3 with the Tomcat plugin. Using Maven and Tomcat, I would like to deploy an embedded instance of the site. My question is how do I configure an additional context path in my embedded Tomcat server?  Below is my Tomcat configuration, but either my `<contextFile>` specification is invalid or the contents of that file (below) are invalid:

```xml
<Context path="/all-new-jx-web" docBase="/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/NissanUSA2/Technology/nna/mycousa/jx/target/web">
</Context>
```

because when I invoke

```
mvn clean -Dmaven.test.skip=true verify -Ptomcat tomcat:run
```

none of the URLs mapped to `/all-new-jx-web` (my additional context path) are getting mapped (assets aren't being served by Tomcat). Any ideas why?  Below is my tomcat profile from my `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<profile>
  <id>tomcat</id>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <contextFile>config/tomcat/context.xml</contextFile>
          <mode>context</mode>
          <addContextWarDependencies>true</addContextWarDependencies>
          <charset>UTF-8</charset>
          <path>/all-new-jx</path>
          <update>true</update>
          <warDirectory>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.${project.packaging}</warDirectory>
          <systemProperties>
            <JAVA_OPTS>-Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:NewRatio=6
                -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled
                -verbose:gc"
            </JAVA_OPTS>
          </systemProperties>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`serverXml`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#serverXml) configuration for that.

Comment: Could you provide an example?  Everything I'm reading about server.xml indicates it is NOT the place where you would add additional context paths for your resources.

Comment: Yes, it is, you are reading the wrong sources. The doc says "server.xml to use Note if you use this you must configure in this file your webapp paths." [This](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc6.0.x/tags/TOMCAT_6_0_32/conf/server.xml) is the default `server.xml`. You put your [contexts](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html#Nested_Components) into the `Host` element.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue.I tried giving location to external server xml but I could get my project to run. Ultimately I ended up modifying the tomcat plugin code to include the additional static context path.

```
// Snippet from AbstractRunMojo.java

            String appBase = new File(configurationDir, "webapps")
                    .getAbsolutePath();
            Host host = container.createHost("localHost", appBase);

            host.addChild(context);
            // Adding static context
            createStaticContext(container, context, host);//More code after this


    private void createStaticContext(final Embedded container, Context context,
        Host host) {
    if (null != staticContextDocbase) {
        Context ctx1 = container.createContext(staticContextPath,
                staticContextDocbase);
        ctx1.setPrivileged(true);
        Wrapper servlet = context.createWrapper();
        servlet.setServletClass(DefaultServlet.class.getName());
        servlet.setName("staticContent");
        ctx1.addChild(servlet);
        ctx1.addServletMapping("/", "staticContent");
        host.addChild(ctx1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got the right idea with your contextFile xml element, but try being explicit instead of using a relative path.

```
<contextFile>${basedir}/config/tomcat/context.xml</contextFile>
```

`${basedir}` is the folder your pom.xml lives in. You might need to change this part if that's not correct for your project.

Answer (score 1):

We needed the same in order to run in dev mode our app, which uses Apache solr. The following seemed to work:

1. declare solr as type=war, scope=tomcat dependency
2. use the tomcat maven plugin (version 1.1) with addContextWarDependencies
3. add system property for solr home as example below

then one can run maven like: **mvn tomcat:run**. Keep in mind that java will require lots of memory in this scenario, so before running maven do **export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1536m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"** for example.

The pom.xml is like, where we assume there are some properties -*including one called solr.home*- read from a config file:

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
  ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
      <artifactId>solr</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.0</version>
      <type>war</type>
      <scope>tomcat</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
  ...
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <addContextWarDependencies>true</addContextWarDependencies>
        <systemProperties>
          <property.you.need>${example.property.yours}</property.you.need>
          <solr.solr.home>${solr.home}</solr.solr.home>
        </systemProperties>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    ...
  </build>
</project>
```

Solr can then be reached in:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/admin
```

and your application in

```
http://localhost:8080/your-app-id/
```

Comment: `tomcat` is NOT a possible value as scope. Possible values are only `provided`, `compile`, `runtime`, `test`, `system`