# Tomcat 7 Maven Plugin multiple context

Tags: tomcat7, maven-tomcat-plugin

In my current state of the pom.xml i have

```
<plugin>  
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>  
  <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
  <version>2.0</version>  
  <configuration>  
    <path>/myPath</path>  
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

this is working fine. I now am trying to add an extra context for the images on the server,
so that the "old" context `/myPath` is directing to the webapp and `/images` can be used to address images.
I have tried to add a context file, but when I do this only my `/images` context is loaded.
Also, I don't want to build the WAR each time (this would be the case if I used two context.xml files for the two contexts)

Is it possible to add a) the context as it is (the current state of development using tomcat7:run AND b) the second context /images that only points to a local folder? 
And how?

Comment: [answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10059792/978502)

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Although it's [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10059792/978502), thought it would be good to post how the xml should look like:</strike>

```
<plugin>  
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>  
  <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
  <version>2.0</version>  
  <configuration>  
    <path>/myPath</path>
    <staticContextPath>/images</staticContextPath>  
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The other answer uses [staticContextDocbase](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-war-only-mojo.html#staticContextDocbase) instead of [staticContextPath](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-war-only-mojo.html#staticContextPath), and I can't tell the difference between the two, but one of then should work. Haven't tried it myself, though ;)

---

**Tomcat's doc of these two properties:**

staticContextDocbase:

> The static context docroot base fully qualified path

staticContextPath:

> The static context

<strike>Could be that `fully qualified path` is in contrast to relative path.</strike>

---

Well, I delved a bit into the plugin and Apache's code and found that you need **both** `staticContextDocbase` and `staticContextPath`.

`staticContextDocbase` is the path from where the static context should be retrieved by Tomcat. In your case it is `C:/images`.

`staticContextPath` is the part in the URL after the `http://<hostname>:<port>` for which the static context should be sent to client. In your case it is `/images`.

Maven should be configured like so:

```
<plugin>  
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>  
  <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
  <version>2.0</version>  
  <configuration>  
    <path>/myPath</path>
    <staticContextPath>/images</staticContextPath>
    <staticContextDocbase>C:/images</staticContextDocbase>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

---

Another note:

[As seen here](https://fisheye6.atlassian.com/viewrep/tomcat/maven-plugin/trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/tomcat/maven/plugin/tomcat7/run/AbstractRunMojo.java?r1=&r2=1312036), the plugin uses [`Tomcat.addContext(String contextPath, String baseDir)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/7.0.0/org/apache/catalina/startup/Tomcat.java#Tomcat.addContext%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%29), `staticContextPath` is passed as `contextPath` and `staticContextDocbase` is passed as `baseDir`. The doc for `baseDir` states that it `Must exist, relative to the server home`.

OTOH, that `baseDir` is moved as is to [`Context.setBaseDir(String docBase)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/7.0.0/org/apache/catalina/Context.java#Context.setDocBase%28java.lang.String%29). The doc on *that* method for `baseDir` states that `This can be an absolute pathname, a relative pathname, or a URL.`.

Try the full path then. If it doesn't work go for the relative ;).

Comment: so how can i link a local folder to the static path then?

Comment: @MatthiasG what do you call `local folder`?

Comment: i would like to have my context ( /myPath ) point to the webapp im developing and localhost:8080/images point to i.e. C:\data\images

Comment: @MatthiasG so try using staticContextDocbase (documented as the fully qualified path of the static context).

Comment: well something like:  
<configuration>  
    <path>/myPath</path>
    <staticContextPath>/images</staticContextPath>  
    <staticContextBasePath>C:/images/</staticContextBasePath>
  </configuration>
wont work

Comment: @MatthiasG `staticContextBasePath` isn't a valid property... Anyway I took another deeper look and updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, my bad i was using `staticContextBasePath` if i do this exactly as stated by you, i get:  `Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.1:run failed: addChild:  Child name '/images' is not unique -> [Help 1]`  (tried both Version: 2.0 and 2.1 )

Comment: @MatthiasG OK that might be some progress. Do you happen to use somewhere the context path `/images`? Maybe in you `server.xml`, `web.xml`?

Comment: @MatthiasG what comes up to my mind is that somehow this child context is added twice, hence the error for any path.

Comment: well i do not add it twice (via code or cinfiguration) also the error shows when i do a maven clean before i run it, so the tomcat configuration is also completely clean

Comment: This is a bug in the tomcat7-maven-plugin that is fixed in 2.3-SNAPSHOT. Try using 2.3-SNAPSHOT and it should work.