# Define context elements in tomcat7-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to display images located in some folder outside of my app using tomcat7-maven-plugin. I ran into this article: https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/how-to-display-images-stored-on-a-server/
It is said that a way to go is to create an xml file defining the context path in tomcat’s conf\Catalina\localhost directory. However, I am using tomcat7-maven-plugin, so I can't find the specified location in there. And I have no idea how to configure it in pom.xml if it's even possible. 
Thank you all in advance!

Comment: In case someone gets into the same trouble, please, follow this link: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674519/tomcat-7-maven-plugin-multiple-context
It worked for me. 
Also, as stated there, tomcat7-maven-plugin is quite buggy, you should use 2.3-SNAPSHOT. Here is a link on how you can set it up properly: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013576/maven-is-failing-to-download-the-tomcat-maven-plugin-snapshot 
(Andre's answer seemed to me the most useful)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `context.xml`  file in your `webapp/META-INF` folder like

```
src
 main
  webapp
   META-INF
    context.xml
   WEB-INF
```

with content that you wish to have.

Or you can add the `allowLinking` attribute to `Context` section and in `webapp` folder create a soft link to the image folder use command `ln -s`.

If you want to package the resource to you app `war`, you can specify it as web resources

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>  

                <webResources>
                    <resource>
<!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory  where can find your images -->

                      <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources
                        </directory>

                    </resource>
                </webResources>    
                <warName>yourwarname</warName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: From Apache: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html

Context elements may be explicitly defined:
In individual files (with a ".xml" extension) in the $CATALINA_HOME/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/ directory. The name of the file (less the .xml) extension will be used as the context path. Multi-level context paths may be defined using #, e.g. foo#bar.xml for a context path of /foo/bar.

I want to apply this to tomcat7-maven-plugin. But there's no conf/Catalina/localhost folder. 

And what you described doesn't work for me