# Tomcat 7 maven plugin complete configuration reference

Tags: maven, tomcat7, maven-tomcat-plugin

I cant seem to find the online reference on tomcat 7 maven plugin configurations.
Example :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>

    <configuration>
        <!-- <server>tomcat7</server> -->
        <path>/</path>
        <aliases>
            <alias>myweb.com</alias>
            <alias>myweb.mydomain.com</alias>
        </aliases>
    </configuration>
    ...
</plugin>
```

Some examples i got so far that shows more of the configuration options:

1. http://mojohaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/usage.html
2. [How do I configure an additional context path for Maven-Tomcat plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984242/how-do-i-configure-an-additional-context-path-for-maven-tomcat-plugin)

But they are not the complete configuration reference. 
I wonder where the configurations reference are located ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reference documentation is available in Apache Tomcat web site.
Try http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.1/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html

Comment: Hello author ! Thanks for the url, but i see that some configurations dont seem to be available in there ? Like the path, charset, and others that seem to be supported based in an example here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984242/how-do-i-configure-an-additional-context-path-for-maven-tomcat-plugin

Comment: correct that's for the deploy goal :-) see http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/tomcat7-maven-plugin/deploy-mojo.html HTH

Comment: My apology for not noticing this. Thanks a lot !